# React-Native Android Build - Could not determine artifacts for com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.2:

Tags: react-native, android-studio

This is a brand new issue. I reviewed the code, and no changes have been made to the libraries in 3 months. All of a sudden I am getting the error "Could not determine artifacts for com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.2:" I tried updating this to 0.9.0+ based on [React Native: App crashes on start due to SoLoader issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60206386/react-native-app-crashes-on-start-due-to-soloader-issue), but then I just got a bunch of "xxxx library uses a deprecated API". I have cleaned the project multiple times, invalidated caches, restarted computer, etc. but I can't find anything about how to fix this problem, nor do I know why it started happening. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Has this issue been resolved? I am facing the same issue.